# IE10: Website security certificate issue + "continue" button missing

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, internet-explorer, ssl, certificate

I am developing a web app and am using self-signed SSL certificates. I'm trying to test my site on Internet Explorer 10 in a modern.ie VM (in VirtualBox). When I visit the site, `https://localIPaddress:3301/`, I get what is pictured at this bottom of this question.

As you can see, there is no option to continue. I've tried everything, and nothing makes it appear...

1. Looked through all options in Internet Options and tried toggling everything I could find related to security and certificates (though it's possible I missed something).
2. Added MinRsaPubKeyBitLength 32-bit DWORD with decimal value 512 to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CertDLLCreateCertificateChainEngine\Config\
3. Added the certificate I'm using to the trusted root certificates via the Internet Options "content" tab
   Ran Internet Explorer as Administrator

and I've rebooted after each of these things. The "continue" link still does not show.

The strange thing is, this same app URL and certificate works in another install of Windows 7 with IE10 under Parallels.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error page's Continue link is hidden:

1. If the certificate is revoked
2. If the certificate is deemed insecure (e.g. contains a 512-bit RSA key)
3. If the page is in a “pinned site” instance
4. If group policy is set to Prevent Ignoring Certificate Errors

Most likely it's #2.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/12/12/ie-website-security-certificate-blocking-page-missing-continue-link.aspx)

> a security update coming to Windows 2008, Win7, Windows Vista, Windows 2003, and Windows XP in August 2012 *will treat as invalid signatures that use RSA keys that are weaker than 1024 bits*.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/13/windows-internet-explorer-block-rsa-key-shorter-than-1024-bits.aspx)

If that update wasn't applied to the Win7 you tested with in Parallels then that would be why it was allowed.

Comment: I tried following http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661254 and running `certutil -setreg chain\minRSAPubKeyBitLength 512` and `certutil -setreg chain\EnableWeakSignatureFlags 2`, but the problem prevails...

Comment: Ah nevermind! Running these commands didn't work, but manually creating the keys did! Thank you!